# Data from Rails class to angularjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, twitter

I created Rails app with Embedded Ruby (erb) as a template engine, I used 'twitter' gem to talk to Twitter API, and created a rails class (called TwitterAPi, inside 'Lib' folder) for that matter. I successfully passed the data to my home.html.erb template, like this:

```
 <ul>
        <% TwitterApi.get_ronaldo_tweets.each do |tweet|%>
        <li><%=  tweet %></li>
        <% end %>
   </ul>
```

Like I've said, TwitterApi is the class that I created and get_ronaldo_tweets is the method in which I pull ronaldo's timeline and share it on my page. (I used application-only authentication)

So, now I want to use Angularjs on frontend, so my question is, is it even possible (and if yes, how it's done?) to use this Rails class with Angular to get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a Rails controller action, to render the tweets as JSON, so that Angular can load them. I recommend you create a **TweetsController**, and just use the index action:

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @tweets = TwitterApi.get_ronaldo_tweets

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { @tweets.to_json }
    end
  end

end
```

Don't forget to define the route in **routes.rb**:

```
resources :tweets, only: :index
```

You may not need to respond to HTML here, but you might want to view the tweets as you currently do in home.html.erb.

You should now be able to see the Tweets JSON by going to:

```
localhost:3000/tweets.json
```

I am just using to_json to dump out the json data, but you might consider [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) or [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) to render the tweets.

Once you have your json data, you can use [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) to load the tweets.

Here is some *untested* AngularJS in CoffeeScript that will hopefully get you started:

```
app = angular.module("RonaldoTweets", ["ngResource"])

app.factory "Tweets", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/tweets.json")
]

@TweetCtrl = ["$scope", "Tweet", ($scope, Tweet) ->
  $scope.tweets = Tweet.query()
```

Finally, you just need the Angular view to display the Tweets. Something like this should work:

```
<div ng-controller="TweetCtrl">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tweet in tweets">
      {{tweet}}
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

[This RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/405-angularjs) explains how to connect an AngularJS app to a Rails resource using ngResource. I recommend you take a look. The only difference here is you are not pulling the Tweets out of a Rails model, you are grabbing them from your TwitterApi Ruby class.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sounds like a nice idea, thanks for the effort!

Comment: Glad it works! I didn't test that Angular code at all, so I expect it will need tweaking. Please do vote up the answer and tick it when you have a chance. Thanks!

Comment: Well I tweaked it a little bit, but the idea was excellent, anyway could you possibly help me with one more thing please? I already had a controller Users and of course I had the usual CRUD options. So now I want for every user to get his Twitter timeline, I already have a method (TwitterApi.get_user_timeline) that takes a parameter of a username, basically it works the same way the ronaldo method does. What I fail to do is how should I "pick up" the combined json from User and Twitter. I tried something like this:

Comment: in UserController def show
user= User.find(params[:id])
username = user.screen_name
userTweets = TwitterApi.get_user_timeline @username

respond_with(sources) do |format|
  format.json  { render :json => {:userTweets => userTweets, 
                                  :user=> user }}

Comment: Could you use the same TweetsController action, and pass in the username in through the params, like:

class TweetsController < ApplicationController

  def index

    tweets = TwitterApi.get_user_timeline(params[:username])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { tweets.to_json }
    end
  end

end 

And, call the tweets action with: /tweets.json?username=ronaldo